# Why does my jQuery animation require an extra click in IE8 to finish?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, internet-explorer-8

I am pretty new to jQuery in general, however the following code works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE8. In IE8, I have to click anywhere on the page to start the animation after selecting a radio button. Here is the code:

```
$("input[name=method]").change(function() {
    if($("input:radio[name=method]:checked").val() == 'installer') {    
        $('#download').slideUp(0).removeClass("vendorSize").text("Download").addClass("installerSize").slideDown(500);      
    }
    else if($("input:radio[name=method]:checked").val() == 'url') {
        $('#download').slideUp(0).removeClass("installerSize").text("Download From Vendor Website").addClass("vendorSize").slideDown(500);
    }
});
```

Anyone know why this breaks in IE8 but not in the other browsers? If you feel this would work better using .animate (not that I think it should matter), can you provide an example of how to code it?

Thanks,

Eric R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE the change event isn't fired directly when you click the radio button, so you have to click somewhere else before it is fired. You can try using the `click` event instead of the change event, that should work.

Comment: Thanks. I swear I had tried to do a click event and it simply broke my entire animation sequence but this definitely worked. Maybe I had a bug in my code before I tried it...

Answer (score 0):

Are the inputs showing?  In IE, any radio or checkbox inputs that are not showing (i.e. that have `display="none"`) will not throw normal click or change events.

Comment: They are all visible (I would provide a link to the page but its behind a login in which I have no control over).

Answer (score 0):

Some events do not propogate in IE the same as in other browsers.  jQuery 1.4 is better than previous versions in this regard.  I have had to put .change() in some of my code to propogate change events such as this - force the .change event using the

```
myselector.trigger('change'); /* we made changes so trigger it */
```

Comment: Where should the .trigger be placed? I am fairly sure I am using an earlier version of jQuery than 1.4. I inherited this website and am currently adjusting it.